# How does one keep multiple dev sandboxes up to date with the upper lifecycles?

Tags: sandbox, git, cicd

Currently there is a gap in our CICD process in my opinion. We have multiple teams working in multiple dev environments, when code is finished in an environment it is then merged into the development branch of our git repo, picked up from there and deployed to the QA box. The issue is that those changes never get written to the dev sandboxes so the code in them is never up to date with current code in the develop git branch unless manually updated in the sandboxes, where problems arise when new fields and objects were created and merged into the dev branch, ultimately slowing down development.

In short my question is, is there a way to keep multiple dev environments in sync without overwriting development that is in progress within those environments other than manually checking code against the dev branch of the git after every deployment?

Comment: IMHO it's developer's responsibility to make sure their sandbox always has latest code. This is the reason why refresh interval for dev sandbox is 1 day. That being said, that ci job that moves code from develop to QA, you could build something similar to update all dev sandboxes. Or you can look into sfdx which ensures code versioning tool is the source of truth and not sandboxes/scratch orgs.